# Apache Virtual Hosts points to wrong DocumentRoot

Tags: debian, virtualhost, apache2, serveralias

I’m running a VPS (Debian 9) with Apache2 service running on it. I want to have a `mail.example.com` direct traffic to `/var/www/mail` and `example.com` to direct traffic to `/var/www/example`. I have written and rewritten the virtual hosts conf many times and `mail.example.com` always directs traffic to the wrong place on my machine.

Could it have something to do with certbot/letsencrypt? I know it changes apache settings. When I first made my SSL cert, I made a rule for `mail.example.com` but “told” let’s encrypt it was located in the other location. Any help would be appreciated.

I will add specific information when I am off of work.

Comment: You should indeed start by providing the configuration that you say is not working because your setup is very very generic, nothing special.

Comment: Hey, I figured it. There were `RewriteEngine` rules at the bottom of my Virtual-Hosts.conf files that I believe were generated by certbot. Removing these lines brought about the intended behavior.

Comment: Then answer your own question and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

There were lines of code that needed to be removed from the virtualhost.conf files. I removed  them and things work as intended.